# Hyperledger fabric Native peer binary not able to communicate with couchdb

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I am facing an issue . I am trying to run peer native binary on  AWS Cloud . My couchdb is already working on the same AWS instance .I have exported all the necessary variable like

`CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=0.0.0.0:5984`
`CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB`
user and password also .

But I am getting error on running command `peer node start` .

```
2018-12-07 08:26:08.622 UTC [couchdb] CreateSystemDatabasesIfNotExist -> ERRO 005 Error during CouchDB CreateDatabaseIfNotExist() for system dbName: _users  error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field DBInfo.purge_seq of type int
2018-12-07 08:26:08.622 UTC [couchdb] VerifyCouchConfig -> ERRO 006 Unable to connect to CouchDB,  error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field DBInfo.purge_seq of type int   Check the admin username and password.
panic: Error in instantiating ledger provider: Unable to connect to CouchDB,  error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field DBInfo.purge_seq of type int   Check the admin username and password.
```

I tried to access the couchdb from browser using fauxton with the same credentials .Its working fine .

Even if I am using this binary on my own system it works fine . But getting error on AWS cloud instance.

coucdb version 2.0

peer binary version 1.2

EDIT: It is now happeing on every ubuntu machine either it is cloud or machine.

Any suggestion please .

Comment: Try using the `localhost:5984` rather than `0.0.0.0:5984`  (assuming they are running on the same instance)

Comment: @GariSingh Issue is that fabric binary is not compatible currently with couchdb version 2.3 .Which is updated by me mistakenly . Going back to version 2.1 solved my problem..

Comment: @PankajCheema How did you degrade couchdb version?Can you please brief me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when I was using the latest version of couchdb i.e 3.2

Please try couchdb v2.1.1. It will work fine.